# error LNK2019, passing vectors through headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My amateur status with C++ might be blinding me from the obvious but I am attempting to write a simple piece of code for a cross product. I would like to make it accessible for future use so I'm attempting to pass the vectors through a header file to a separate .cpp. This is what I have right now:

**.cpp for Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

// Custom Functions
#include "G:\Visual Studio\source\repos\Functions\Functions\Functions.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<double> r_0(3), v_0(3), h(3);

    double X_0[1][6] = {
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,   1.0, 0.0 }
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        r_0[j] = X_0[0][j];
        v_0[j] = X_0[0][j + 3];
    };

    XP_Function h_func;
    h = h_func.X_Product(r_0, v_0);
    std::cout << h[0] << " " << h[1] << " " << h[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**.h for header**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class XP_Function {
public:
    std::vector<double> X_Product(std::vector<double> u, std::vector<double> v);

private:
    std::vector<double> XP;
};
```

**.cpp for function**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "Functions.h"

std::vector<double> XP_Function::X_Product(std::vector<double> u, std::vector<double> v) {
    std::vector<double> XP(3);

    XP[0] = u[1] * v[2] - u[2] * v[1];
    XP[1] = u[2] * v[0] - u[0] * v[2];
    XP[2] = u[0] * v[1] - u[1] * v[0];

    return XP;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> > __thiscall XP_Function::X_Product(class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> >,class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> >)" (?X_Product@XP_Function@@QAE?AV?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@V23@0@Z) referenced in function _main
1>G:\Visual Studio\source\repos\Test\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I'd appreciate any insight. Apologies if it's just a simple mistake. I really just started a week ago with only one course in this from a year ago.

Comment: You probably don't build with both source files. It's not enough to have it on the disk, all source files must be in the actual Visual Studio project as well.

Comment: As in, I need to go into the function .cpp and hit build before I try running the main .cpp?

Comment: In Visual Studio you have your tree structure containing the main source file. That's not enough, you must list all source files needed for the project there. If the `Function.cpp` file (or whatever it's named) is not in that list, it will not be built together with the main source file.

Comment: @Max No everything in the project gets built at the same time, but you need to add function.cpp to the project.

Comment: Yeah, gotcha. Thanks! That actually got it to run without errors but now I can't keep the output window open to check and see if it's working as intended. Usually CTRL+F5 does the trick but it's just popping up and closing.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot I needed to go into properties and change the console settings. Thanks guys! You really helped me out and practically immediately!